# Ajax -Append data to URL

Tags: javascript, ajax

I'm working with Ajax for the first time and I want to append two data on the URL.
Here's the code I'm using - is not working.

How can I append two values in the destination URL?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(first, second)
{
if (first =="" || second =="" )
  {
  document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("searchDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?type="+first&"place"=+second,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
```

The data appended to the url does not seem to be correct. I'm appending data to `type` and `place`
[Here's the example](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp) I'm using, it takes one value but I want to make mine accept two values.
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

typo

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?type="+first&"place"=+second,true);
```

should be

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","search.php?type="+first+"&place="+second,true);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but it's still not working. I don't know - do you think the code itself is correct?

Comment: @Julie:  Please take alook at [jQuery](http://jquery.com) - to do the same, use `$("#searchDiv").load("search.php?type="+first&"place"=+second)`

Comment: There's a [campaign to clean up Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167342/187073) by removing these typo-related questions - we could really use your help! Would you mind pitching in a little by casting a close vote on this question?